# AWS cp not copying all files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-copying

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

aws s3 cp s3://abc/$line s3://xyz/  --profile prod --recursive

done < "$1"
```

In the terminal I'm using

```
./s3-copy.sh images-to-copy.txt
```

images-to-copy.txt is:
15.jpeg
16.jpeg
17.jpeg

This is only copying the last element into my S3 bucket i.e. 17.jpeg. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with the command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS S3 Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Sample Command: `aws s3 sync s3://$SOURCE_BUCKET/ .`